# How to verify SSL using WordPress wp_remote_get() function?

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress native function `wp_remote_get` and `wp_remote_retrieve_response_code` like below:

```
$wpfs_response  =   wp_remote_get ( get_site_url() );           
$wpfs_response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code ( $wpfs_response );
```

**Now, using the above code how can I verify:**

> - SSL found,
> - SSL found but not a valid certificate

any idea or solution?

Comment: try is_ssl() function

Comment: @ManishNegi so we can't check using that wp_remote_get() function?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, you can't.

To get the cert data and know if there's a valid cert, requires a different approach. This is the function I use, inspired by the one found in Really Simple SSL plugin on Wordpress.org.

```
function get_ssl_data( $domain ) {
    $url = 'https://' . str_replace( array( 'https://', 'http://' ), '', $domain );

    $original_parse = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST );
    if ( $original_parse ) {
        $get = stream_context_create( array( "ssl" => array( "capture_peer_cert" => true ) ) );
        if ( $get ) {
            set_error_handler( '__return_true' );
            $read = stream_socket_client( "ssl://" . $original_parse . ":443", $errno, $errstr, 5, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $get );
            restore_error_handler();

            if ( ! $read ) {
                $certinfo = 'no-response';
            }

            if ( $errno == 0 && $read ) {
                $cert = stream_context_get_params( $read );
                if ( isset( $cert['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate'] ) ) {
                    $certinfo = openssl_x509_parse( $cert['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate'] );
                } else {
                    $certinfo = 'no-response';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $certinfo;
}
```

Please note that:

- this is using the `__return_true` WordPress' function to provide a `set_error_handler` callback for errors;
- in order to check if there's a valid cert, use `is_array( get_ssl_data( $domain ) )`